# XCode 7.2.1 Empty Provisioning profile

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode7, provisioning-profile

I have a problem with XCode 7.2.1. From a bit of time unfortunately, every time I open a project of an app developed for IOS I never had to set up the Provisioning Profile. It is always empty:

[image: [Figure 1]]

And also if I try to choose makes me appear a box with a free-field instead of a combo with the choice of the provisioning profile:

[image: [Figure 2]]

I have done all the appropriate tests, I installed the beta version of XCode, but nothing, I installed the Beta version of El Capitan, but unfortunately without result.

I have also installed the 7.0.1 version of XCode because I thought I was wrong and instead I have always the same error. Is there a solution that is not reinstalling the operating system?

Comment: I have re-installed the operating system on El Capitan. Nothing still does not work. I don't know what to do

Comment: Have you signed into your apple developer account in Xcode?

Comment: Yes i signed into Apple Developer Account

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if it can be useful to someone but in the end I solved the problem. 
I re-installed Yosemite, and I have not had any kind of problem. 
I visualize correctly the combo is on the certificate that the Provisioning Profile. 
I think it is a problem of the Operating System. 
Thank you all for the support

Comment: I don't see how the OS could be a factor in this. This is most likely an Xcode, or .. ahem ... user issue